# Java, send mail using SMTP always mail goes to spam folder, Why?

Tags: java, gmail

i'm say apology to ask this repeated Question..

i'm using gmail smtp server to send mails..

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

But always my mail sending spam folder only....

Note: i'm using gmail as company name  `myname@mtmr.in`

if it is normal gmail like myname@gmail.com,, it is working fine.. but i want through company mail..

Comment: Stop sending SPAM then.  Seriously, are you sending from mtmr.in?

Comment: yes.. all mails are sending through company mail id..

Comment: Are you setting reasonable headers?

Comment: i'm setting like this.. Message msg = new MimeMessage(session); msg.addHeader("X-Priority", "1");

Comment: Google should give the reason that it is spam.

Comment: how to rectify this problem is their any solution???

Comment: @java have you got a solution? I am still facing it. Few of the recipient is getting in spam. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say for sure why your email is being marked as SPAM, but one possibility<sup>1</sup> is that your company has gotten itself a reputation for spamming.  (Or more precisely, lots of gmail users have hit the "report spam" button on emails that they received from your company.)

If that is the problem, then there is not much you can do about that except create a filter on *your* gmail account to move those emails out of your spam.  Of course, that only affects emails *going to your account* ... not anyone else's.

The long term remedy is to convince the people who are sending spam / spammy messages using your company's email address to STOP IT!

---

<sup>1 - The fact that the same email sent using your personal email address is NOT marked as SPAM suggests that this is more than just "a possibility" ...</sup>